# Certificate Checking for MITM w/ Squid

Tags: certificates, proxy, squid

I have already set up a squid cache proxy server on a Raspberry Pi 4. I need to create some sort of GUI to turn on and off certificate checking for man in the middle attacks.

First, how do I get squid to do this certificate checking, or do I need another program to do the work. Is it possible to then create a GUI program to then let the user turn on and off the certificate checking thing.

Comment: *"I need to create some sort of GUI ..."* - as far as I understand you are basically asking for a GUI to easily reconfigure squid in a specific way. This is not a security question.

Comment: I'm asking what I need to do to have certificate checking for mitm with squid. The GUI is later, asking if its possible to do so.

Comment: So you are looking for the appropriate configuration option? See [sslproxy_cert_error](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/sslproxy_cert_error/).